# Sublime prints error despite successfully building Python files

Tags: python, sublimetext3

When I use the build command, Sublime runs my Python files fine but also generates an error that I can't make sense of.  What is going on here?  I'm using Sublime Text 3 on Windows 10 Pro.

hello.py

```
print('hello')
```

Output (with newlines added for readability)

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
hello
[Finished in 0.2s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u "C:\Users\mmarchese\Desktop\test2.py" ]
[dir: C:\Users\mmarchese\Desktop]
[path:
C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jre-13.0.1.9-hotspot\bin;
C:\Python38\Scripts\;
C:\Python38\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;
C:\WINDOWS\system32;
C:\WINDOWS;
C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;
C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Client Access\Emulator;
C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Client Access\Shared;
C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Client Access\;
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;
C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;
C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\;
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;
C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;
C:\Program Files\nodejs\;
C:\Users\mmarchese\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;]
```

Each of these works fine when run via the Windows command prompt

- `python hello.py`
- `C:\Python38\Python.exe hello.py`

Python.sublime-build

```
{
    "shell_cmd": "python -u \"$file\"",
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python",

    "env": {"PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8"},

    "variants":
    [
        {
            "name": "Syntax Check",
            "shell_cmd": "python -m py_compile \"${file}\"",
        }
    ]
}
```